# protobuf IDL --> JSON schema

Tags: protocol-buffers, jsonschema

I want to auto-convert protobuf IDL (sans `service` specs) to JSON schema as part of a build process. Does there exist a tool I can use for this purpose and if so what is it?

Comment: Protobuf is a serialization format, Json-Schema is a description and validation format. Json-Schema spec is also much broader than protobuf. What is the purpose of such transformation?

Comment: I'm normalizing different message types (i.e. not just Protobufs, other message formats) to JSON; for validation purposes I'd like to normalize their descriptions to JSON schema (and the two processes are happening in different places so validation can't just happen when the messages are normalized).

Comment: So if I understood correctly you need to keep a PB and Json-Schema definition synchronized with its relative messages in order to perform a double validation. I doubt you have anything out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt I have anything out of the box either... which is why I'm feeling kinda miffed that I haven't found anything that does what I want... -.-' I mean, it's not too much to sort of hack something on top of protoc, but, still...

Comment: try this https://github.com/turn/shapeshifter

Comment: I think it's better going from JSON Schema to Protobuf instead as per @jruizaranguren comment.

Answer (score 10):

I have found this one interesting: https://github.com/devongovett/protobuf-jsonschema

Comment: It's been unaswered since 2014. I don't care about rep if this can be helpful to someone! Also look at my last answer date to know that grabbing a point or 2 is not my goal. Pfff...